# How do I import columns into Excel from SQL in the same order as they are in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, excel, export-to-excel

I created a 'vwTable' view on SQL Server with the following column order:

```
Shift_id | Client_ip | Machine_Center
```

but when I select the view using "get external data" from Excel:

```
SELECT * FROM vwTable
```

The order of the columns in Excel is not the same; the output is:

```
Machine_Center | Client_ip | Shift_id
```

From SSMS:

[image]

From Excel:

[image]

How can I get the column order to be the same in Excel as it is in SSMS?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. right click EXCEL column header

   - go to Table => external table properties
   - Uncheck `"Preserve column sort/filter/layout"`
   - Refresh Excel
2. right click Excel column header

   - go to Table => external table properties
   - check `"Preserve column sort/filter/layout"`
   - Refresh Excel

The order of the columns in Excel are now the same order as they are in the SQL View.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just name them in your select?

```
Select Shift_id, Client_ip, Machine_Center from vwTable
```