# macOS Connector/MySQL ODBC driver could not be loaded in Excel for Mac 2016

Tags: mysql, excel, macos, iodbc

I am working with Excel for Mac Version 16.18 on High Sierra 10.13.6. Installed Connector/ODBC 8.0.12 for macOS, tested the connection to my database with iODBC Data Source Administration (64-Bit) and worked:

[image: iODCB Data Source Administrator]

When I try connecting with Excel with the save driver and credentials I get the following error:

[image: IM003 iODBC Driver Manager Specified driver could not be loaded]

Same problem with both, Unicode and ANSI drivers.

Comment: Does it support the version of excel that you have? Are both appropriately up-to-date?

Comment: I installed iODBC and the MySQL ODBC driver today, iODBC is verion 3.52.12 and the Connector/ODBC is version 8.0.12, all up-to-date according to Apple Open Source and MySQL sites.

Answer (score 12):

I was able to connect to MySQL with Microsoft Excel Version 16.19 by making the following adjustments:

1. I copied the driver's whole directory /mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.12-macos10.13-x86-64bit to /Library/ODBC (why? see https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89931, and [Is there a way to get ADODB to work with Excel for Mac 2011?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707256/is-there-a-way-to-get-adodb-to-work-with-excel-for-mac-2011/52636603#52636603)) ; basically the reason for that is the driver gets downloaded to /usr/local and Excel, being sandboxed, cannot access that location.
2. Updated the file odbc.ini, also located in /Library/ODBC, with the driver's new location.

Comment: This is a great answer, worked for me too when I was almost ready to give up on the idea of using the factory driver, and shell out the €40 for the commercial driver from Actual...

Comment: The following github issue discusses this problem too and somebody posted a script to fix the installation automatically: https://github.com/openlink/iODBC/issues/29#issuecomment-426790551

Comment: I have a new problem after I apply this method.  " [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver]Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (1) ". I guess the reason is Excel in sandbox can not visit /tmp/mysql.sock, but I do not know how to fix it,

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this as well and I fixed it by changing ALL odbc.ini files to whatever you want change to. I think somehow excel use other odbc.ini files that are not in/Library/ODBC directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it:

Go to the "ODBC Drivers Tab," select de driver and "Configure the driver," then add the odbcinst.ini path in the "Setup file name":

[image]