# Mysql odbc excel on mac in the year 2021

Tags: mysql, excel, macos, odbc

I have tried the following which basically involves moving the odbc stuff in to a library folder and updating the odbc.ini or adding it to iODBC:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-installation.html
[macOS Connector/MySQL ODBC driver could not be loaded in Excel for Mac 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52896893/macos-connector-mysql-odbc-driver-could-not-be-loaded-in-excel-for-mac-2016/53012994#53012994)

I got the usual:
[iODBC][Driver Manager]dlopen(/Users/henriettamartingale/Library/ODBC/lib/libmyodbc8w.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
file system sandbox blocked open() of '/Users/henriettamartingale/Library/ODBC/lib/libmyodbc8w.so'

I'm using a macOS Big Sur (for the first time in my life.  It's mandatory.  Alas...) version 11.4
Excel for Mac 16.50 (21061301)

Further, adding Excel to the full disk access list did not work.  I think I have to add the odbc something or other to that list.  What would I add?

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your libraries to somewhere like /Library/ODBC. You can either do this by building the relevant libraries yourself with --prefix or you can use install_name_tool -change on the libraries themselves (once you have moved them)to make sure all the references now point to somewhere within /Library.

Comment: I tried that and it didnt' work. Ultimately I paid for a solution that worked on the first try.

Comment: For information: this does indeed seem to be a bug in psqlodbc. It works with mysql.