# Alternative way to read data in adodb with mac excel

Tags: excel, vba, macos

All my data was store in a worksheet named "OrderData".(Only 1 table)

And I used the script as below to process data in Windows environment.

But recently I found that this script didn't work with Mac excel due to mac didn't support adodb.

So I am wonder if there is an alternative way to process worksheet data like this way in Mac excel. (excel version 2016↑)

```
Sub Main
   Dim sql as string = "select customer, orderNo from [OrderData$]"
   Set rs = ExecuteSQL(sql)
End Sub

Function ExecuteSQL(sql As String) As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"";"
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rs.Open sql, conn
    
    Set ExecuteSQL = rs

End Function
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707256/is-there-a-way-to-get-adodb-to-work-with-excel-for-mac-2011

Comment: I don't have Mac to test this but did you try to query using $, worksheet name ,using built-in QueryTables feature such as: "select customer, orderNo from [OrderData$]" ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @FunThomas !

I create a worksheet "QueryResult" to save queryTable.

And I modified the code as below. It works fine in windows environment.

I will send to my coworkers to try in Mac excel since I don't have mac.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim sqlstr As String
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    
    sqlstr = "select * from [OrderData$]"
    
    Set qt = ExecuteQuery(sqlstr)
    Debug.Print "query result rows count:" & UBound(qt.ResultRange.Value)

End Sub

Function ExecuteQuery(sqlstr As String) As QueryTable

    Dim connstring As String
    Dim wbName As String
    Dim wsResult As Worksheet
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    
    Set wsResult = Worksheets("QueryResult")
    
    wsResult.Cells.Clear
    
    For Each qt In wsResult.QueryTables
        qt.Delete
    Next qt
    
    wbName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        
    connstring = "ODBC;DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};Dbq=" + wbName + ";"

    With wsResult.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=wsResult.Range("A1"), sql:=sqlstr)
      .BackgroundQuery = False
      .Refresh
    End With
    

    Set ExecuteQuery = wsResult.QueryTables(1)

End Function
```